# Multi Site WordPress 4.7.4 -- new sites overwrite blog id 1

Tags: wordpress, snapshot, multisite

I have a small sandbox wordpress multisite where I create sandbox sites for users of my main installation to test theme and structural changes.

I have a root site (id 1), 3 working as intended sites (ids 2,3,4 respectively) but now whenever I create an additional site instead of making ID 5, it overwrites ID 1. In the database it doesn't even create the tables for blog ID 5, it just overwrites or adds to the tables for blog ID 1.

The only thing unique about this site versus my other multisites is that we copy sites from **proddomain.com** to the **sandbox.com** site via the plugin Snapshot.

Does anyone have any idea what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

The error had to do with another admin's attempt to change the apache configuration and use **sitea.com** at **sitesomeotherurlthatwastemporary.com** without doing all the required DB updates. Something was missed in the cleanup and was permanently broken until I completely reinstalled from scratch and used the snapshot plugin to migrate my sites over to the fresh install.

Lesson: don't try to change wordpress urls without changing all the tables in the database.